# Yes/No Is $p^2 \le y^2$?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

> Given  $z= x+iy$ and $m=  p + iq$ be  complex number  such that  $p^2 = z^2 +1 $

Is  the  following inequalities  always  True ? Yes/No

$p^2 \le y^2$

My attempt  :  I think  No , take $y=0$ , $p=1$

Is its correct ?

Comment: $p^{2} = z^{2} + 1 = x^{2} - y^{2} + 1 + i2xy$, is a complex number, It makes no sense to compare it with a real number

Comment: @ZAF  every real  number  is a  complex number

Comment: I know, but how do you compare them? Who is bigger, $1$ or $i$?

Comment: i thinks  both are  equal  beacuse   i  mean $ y $ coorddinate $1$

Comment: Well... who is bigger $2$ or $1 + i$? Hahaha

Comment: $2 > 1+i$@ZAF,,

Comment: But you say $i$ is equal to $1$, so $i = 1 \implies i +1 = 2$,

Comment: okss thanks u @ZAF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just say “take $y=0$, $p=1$” without defining $z$. But, if you take $x=0$ too, then $z=x+yi=0$ and, indeed, $p^2=z^2+1$. And then, yes, $p^2>y^2$.

Comment: okss @ jose  carlos sir   but  every real  number is  a  complex number

Comment: Yes. I know that.